# Converting LINQ expression to expression tree queryable.Where(c => c.Tags != null && searchValues.All(s => c.Tags.Contains(s)));

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, expression, expression-trees

I have a list of strings `string[] searchValues` and a LINQ expression

```
queryable.Where(c => c.Tags != null && searchValues.All(s => c.Tags.Contains(s)));
```

where `.Tags` is a `List<string>`

I want to rewrite it as an expression (filters and sorting orders are coming from UI as strings, and I wanted to create a generic method to convert it to expressions)

So far I've written this, but it's incorrect.

```cs
private static Expression GetFilterExpressionIListString2(MemberExpression memberExp, string[] values)
{
    
    var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var specificAnyMethod = anyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
    Expression<Func<List<string>, bool>> lambda = s => values.All(v => s.Contains(v));
    var anyExp = Expression.Call(specificAnyMethod, memberExp, lambda);
    var notNullExp = Expression.NotEqual(memberExp, Expression.Constant(null));
    var andExp = Expression.AndAlso(notNullExp, anyExp);
    return andExp;
}
```

```
// an example of a dynamicly built tree that works
// .Tags.Wheere(x => x != null && values.Contains(x.Title))
private static Expression GetFilterExpressionString(MemberExpression memberExp, string[] values)
{
    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(ICollection<string>).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    ConstantExpression constantExp = Expression.Constant(values);
    MethodCallExpression containsExpression = Expression.Call(constantExp, containsMethod, memberExp);
    return containsExpression;
}
```

Comment: Do you know that your query is not translatable by EF Core?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the query that I gave as an example is translatable. But I need to dynamically adjust it based on string filter values coming from UI (i.e. change the field that is being compared, etc).

So instead of queryable.Where(c => c.Tags != null && searchValues.All(s => c.Tags.Contains(s))); 

it can be queryable.Where(c => c.Tags != null && searchValues.All(s => c.Posts.Contains(s))); (etc, quite many variants)

So I wanted to use expressions for it

Comment: Sorry, which EF Core version supports this? I can generate ANY LINQ expression dynamically but i need to ensure that i have not spend my time for nothing.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's MongoDb driver, I've updated the question with one example which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function generates needed Lambda body:

```cs
private static Expression GetFilterExpressionIListString2(MemberExpression memberExpression, string[] values)
{
    var param          = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "s");
    var valuesConstant = Expression.Constant(values);

    var allLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains), new[] { typeof(string) },
            valuesConstant, param), param);

    var filterExpression =
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.NotEqual(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(null, memberExpression.Type)),
            Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.All), new[] { typeof(string) }, valuesConstant, allLambda)
        );

    return filterExpression;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I think memberExpression (the (x => x.Tags), the selector - is never passed to allLambda - it is only checked for null, but not filtered by .Contains

Comment: Yes, the last expression call should have a parameter `memberExpression` instead of `valuesConstant` - but after this change it works perfectly!

Thanks so much, you're a beast